# [ERROR]java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:1

Tags: java, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have executed the below java script in the informatica java transformation but I'm getting the error: `[ERROR]java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:1`

```
String [] Name_parsed;
String Name_delimiter = "&";
String  Name_li = Name;
int Name_length = Name_li.length();

for (int i=0; i < Name_length; i++) 
{
    Name_parsed = Name.split(Name_delimiter);

    o_Name =Name_parsed[0];
    generateRow();

    o_Name =Name_parsed[1];
    generateRow();

}
```

Comment: What is the value of `Name`?

Comment: Check the length of `Name_parsed` before accessing `[0]` or `[1]`. You don't know for sure if it's a 2-length array

Answer (score 2):

Chances are, your input string has fewer than 1 `&` character.  Try printing the `Name` variable to see if this is the case.  You can always wrap this in a `try/catch` block to handle these cases.

Answer (score 2):

The error mean that you have array that length is lower then 1.

This mean that `Name.split(Name_delimiter)` return array with only one element.

and when you try to access to index `1` here `o_Name =Name_parsed[1];` it can not found it.

Validate your input data.

Answer (score 1):

If there can be variable number of "&"(s) in the Name field, you should do it like this:

```
String [] Name_parsed;
String Name_delimiter = "&";
String  Name_li = Name;
int Name_length = Name_li.length();

for (int i=0; i < Name_length; i++) 
{
    Name_parsed = Name.split(Name_delimiter);

    for (int j=0; j<Name_parsed.length; j++){
    {
        o_Name =Name_parsed[j];
        generateRow();
    }

}
```